# How can I hide the wires to a self-made ceiling light fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling, light-fixture

I have a simple self-made ceiling light fixture, but it currently lacks two things:

1. some kind of a pipe to hide the wire.
2. a cover to hide the ceiling junction box.

I'd like to use something similar to what's used on this fixture to hide the wires in the ceiling, but I'm not sure what it's called or where I should look for it.

[image]

I also need to figure out how to hide the wires between the ceiling and the fixture itself.

What types of ready-made products should I use for this type of project?

Comment: I'm not sure I should advocate self-made fixtures, but a picture would be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for different options to meet the needs you've specified, or are you asking the community to shop for you?  If you want to know what options you have, you may want to edit the question and add more detail (and pictures).  If you are simply looking for somebody to send you links to products on Amazon, this question will likely be closed as "Off-Topic".  Since you don't have enough reputation, you won't be able to add images. If you upload them to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post a link in a comment, a higher rep user will be able to edit them into the question.

Comment: @Tester101: OK. I was looking for someone to shop for me. DIY is related with shopping a lot. I guess I need another site for that. No, there is 0 offers on amazon. Yes, I have been googling and looking around shops for quite a while. This question can be deleted (or can I do it?). In case someone else have the same problem, he/she will have to look for better community.

Comment: Just in case: [here can be seen](http://kriste3.fatcow.com/Blog/Malaysia-0114.jpg) what I am looking for - this little cup (or whatever it is called) that is right next to the ceiling.

Comment: @Yored No problem, we'll see how the question does in it's new form (no guarantees).

Comment: What do you mean "ceiling socket"? Is it an outlet that takes a standard two or three prong plug? Is is a screw in base for a bulb? Is it an exposed outlet box?

Comment: Socket might not be the right name (excuse my English): [here can be seen what it is](http://www.hammerzone.com/archives/elect/fixture/lighting/chandelier/elfxca03a.jpg). I guess it is called an electrical or junction box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a condiment cup or similar and just drill a hole in the middle of the bottom. [Here's one](http://www.crateandbarrel.com/stainless-steel-small-2.5-condiment-prep-cup/s609013), that runs $1.50, but there will likely be about a billion to choose from, so you can surely find the right diameter somewhere.

Comment: Yes, some cups could be used...

Answer (score 1):

For hanging pendants, provided the shade isn't really heavy, the wiring *is* the cable. Not sure the look you are going for, but black heavy-duty extension chord strips work well.

As Decorator states, a cup is a good idea for the plate cover. I'd consider maybe considering a small stainless steel bowl (again, depending on the look you are going after).

Ikea's marketplace is a great place for picking up parts for lamp ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any metal cup. It is conducting. On electric failure the cup may be on the high potential. At least you should connect the PE wire with a crimped lug and a screw to the metal cup.

You can buy these in all colours and made from insulating material. Keep an eye on the pull relief on the bottom. You will find big difference in quality here. A good system was used by many IKEA lamps.

In Germany these things are called "Baldachin"; in English its baldachin or canopy.
Try to search for it in combination with "lamp" as a keyword.